# Differential 1-form for $f(x,y) = \sin(x^2 + y^2)$ on vector field $\mathbf{A}=x\partial_x + y\partial_y$

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry

I was doing some research into differential 1-forms and came across a problem which asks for the differential 1-form $\omega = df$ on the vector field $\mathbf{A}=x\partial_x + y\partial_y$ if $f(x,y) = \sin(x^2 + y^2)$.

So I undertand that if $\omega$ is a differential 1-form then it can be expressed as $\omega=df=F(x,y)dx+G(x,y)dy=2x\cos(x^2+y^2)dx + 2y\cos(x^2+y^2)dy$. But $dx$ and $dy$ have vector arguments, so as a function of $\textbf{A}$ this is $\omega(\textbf{A})=2x\cos(x^2+y^2)dx(\textbf{A}) + 2y\cos(x^2+y^2)dy(\textbf{A})=2x\cos(x^2+y^2)A_x + 2y\cos(x^2+y^2)A_y$

In this case, the solution to the problem reads that $A_x = x$ and $A_y = y$, but why is this so, and what is the meaning of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ in this problem (i.e. what are we taking partial derivatives of)?

Answer (score 1):

Formula (definition of differential):
$$dx (\alpha (x,y) \partial_x + \beta (x,y) \partial_y) = \alpha (x,y) $$
Analogously for $dy $.

Comment: So does $dx$ simply extract the $x$ component? If so, why is $\alpha$ the component that is left over?

Comment: Yes, $dx $ extracts the coefficient for $\partial_x $. And $\alpha $ is that coefficient in my formula.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering why this is so. Why is it the case that whatever is in front of $\partial_x$ is actually the $x$ component of the vector?

Comment: $dx $ is defined to be a linear mapping such that $dx^i (\partial_j) = \delta^i_j $ where $i $ and $j $ index over the dimensions ($x^i$ are the coordinates) and $\delta^i_j $ is the Kronecker delta having value $1$ when $i=j $, value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: In mathematics one way to define vector fields is as derivatives (acting on some scalar field). It's principally the direction derivative $\vec v \cdot \nabla \phi $, and $\vec v $ is identified with this directional derivative.

Comment: Ah, so the $x$ coordinate of $v$ is the coefficient of $\partial_x \phi$?

Comment: That's correct.